# Cypress Request on Page Reload

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to trigger a Cypress request on page reload?

I am wondering if it is possible to trigger a Cypress request on page reload?

I can reload the page with cy.reload(). I can also trigger an API request with cy.request().

However, I am not sure how to make an API request WHEN the page is reloaded.

I am still learning Cypress, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the application reloading the webpage itself, or are you triggering it via `cy.reload()`?